# как настроить авто-перезагрузку страницы с параметром public

Tags: javascript, webpack, browsersync

*`$ webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`*

При таких настройках открывается браузер по адресу *http://localhost:8092/* и при изменении файла **index.js** происходит перезагрузка страницы

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

conf = {

    entry: './efwf/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, './dist' ),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },

};

module.exports = conf;
```

но мне нужно что бы открывался например адрес сайта на wordpress exemple.com и я добавил в файл строчку **public**

```
const path = require('path');

conf = {

    entry: './efwf/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, './dist' ),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },

    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        public: "http://exemple.com",

        contentBase: path.join( __dirname, './' ),
        watchContentBase: true
    },

};

module.exports = conf;
```

теперь все как нужно но не происходит перезагрузка странице при изменении файла **index.js** ,
что нужно сделать что бы она все-же *перезагружалась* ?

( то-есть не важно какой адрес сайта я туда напишу и имеет ли он отношения к файлу **index.js** или **bundle.js** ,главное чтобы происходила *перезагрузка* страницы )

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, при использовании инлайн режима (inline mode) и прокси-сервера (dev-server) встроенный клиентский скрипт не всегда знает, к чему подключиться. Он попытается угадать URL-адрес сервера на основе `window.location`, но если это не удается, нужно прописать [devServer.public](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-public) как вы и сделали:

```
devServer: {
    overlay: true,
    public: "exemple.com:80",

    contentBase: path.join( __dirname, './' ),
    watchContentBase: true
},
```

Однако, протокол указывать наверняка не нужно, а также необходимо указать порт, на котором располагается ваш сайт. По умолчанию в протоколе HTTP используется порт 80, а в протоколе HTTPS порт 443, даже значения по-умолчанию я бы рекомендовал указывать. То же самое пишут и в примерах документации у `webpack`. Файл конфигурации вы поправили, однако скрипт не поправили. Скрипт будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
webpack-dev-server --public exemple.com:80
```

Хотел написать комментарий, но получилось многовато текста. Также, рекомендую проверить брандмауэр, чтобы он не блокировал порт, через который вы будете *ходить*. Возможно в вашем случае даже скрипт менять не нужно и достаточно просто настроить фаервол и(или) антивирус.

---

**UPD:** также, на просторах интернета наткнулся на интересную страницу: [Отладка на локальных устройствах приложений под webpack-dev-server](https://blog.zverit.com/frontend/2018/02/12/webpack-dev-server-on-localhost-devices/). В качестве дополнения к ответу приведу информацию из источника:

1. Узнать IP машины на которой будет запущен `webpack-dev-server`. (Команды `ipconfig` (Windows) или `ifconfig` (Linux)), к примеру будет `'192.168.3.186'`.
2. Запустить `webpack-dev-server` на этом IP:

   ```
   devServer: {
       hot: true,
       contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
       publicPath: '/',
       host: '192.168.3.186'
       port: 7373,
       proxy: {
         '/api/**': {
           target: '192.168.3.186:8000',
           secure: false,
           changeOrigin: true,
         }
       },
     },
   ```
3. Отключить Public Firewall в Windows Defender или другой, если используется сторонний.
4. Можно использовать на других устройствах, обращаясь по адресу машины на котором запущен `dev-server`, не забывая указывать нужный порт. В данном случае `192.168.3.186:7373`.

Данный метод я не использовал, но кажется, что попробовать стоит. Да, в статье указано, что данный подход используется в качестве отладки, но если зайти с другой стороны, то на машине, с которой запущен хостинг при изменении кода будет рефрешиться страница, которая хостится (возможно немного не то, что нужно, но оставлю в качестве дополнения).